# Use results of one service call within another (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently making a call to a service method to return player profiles within my Angular app. I then need to immediately 'massage' some of the returned data by utilizing the results from another service method call. I'm wondering whether I am structuring my controller correctly below, or if I should make my `codesService` call within the `$promise` resolution of my `playersService` call instead.

Note: The controller below is a simplified version of my actual controller. The actual controller involves 'massaging' over a dozen elements.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gameApp')
  .controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

ProfileController.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'playersService', 'codesService'];

function ProfileController($routeParams, playersService, codesService) {
  var vm = this;
  var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;
  var codes;

  var getCodes = function() {
    codesService.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
      codes = data;
    });
  };

  var getProfiles = function() {
    playersService.getProfiles({
      playerId: playerId
    }).$promise.then(function(profiles) {
      for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
        profiles[i].name = codes.MSP[profiles[i].MSPkey].name;
      }
      vm.profiles = profiles;
    });
  };

  var init = function() {
    getCodes();
    getProfiles();
  };

  init();
}
```

Comment: You should do this "massaging" in a service... The controller should be "thin". Also, you have a race condition here between `codeService.get` resolving and `playersService.getProfile` resolving

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should be very simple and get directly and exactly what it needs.

```
.controller("ProfileController", function(profileService, $routeParams){
  var vm = this;
  var playerId = $routeParams.playerId;

  profileService.getProfiles(playerId)
    .then(function(profiles){
       vm.profiles = profiles;
    });
});
```

`profileService` should just return everything neatly tied and packaged.

It will need to use the other services (i.e. `codesService`, `playersService`) as dependencies. And also, as I mentioned in the comments (and a few others in their answers), you can invoke the calls to `codesService` and `playersService` in parallel, but you **must** wait for both to finish.

```
.factory("profileService", function($q, codeService, playersService){
  var svc = {
    getProfiles: function(playerId){
      $q.all({ 
          players: getPlayers(playerId),
          codes:   getCodes()
        })
        .then(function(data){
           var players = data.players;
           var codes = data.codes;

           return DoMassaging(players, codes);
        })
    }
  };

  return svc;
});
```

Make sure that `getPlayers()` and `getCodes()` return their respective promises.

Answer (score 0):

If a `then` method returns a promise then Angular will use the results of the second promise for any subsequent `then()`] calls.

But all you really have here is a situation where you need both promises before you can progress, and for that you need is `$q.all()`

(Also, just return a promise from your service methods.  The indirection doesn't improve your code.)

`$q.all([getCodes(), getProfiles()).then(function(data)) {
     var codes = data[0];
     var profiles = data[1];
  }`

If you don't like the array arithmetic you can split it into two phases by chaining your then() calls.

Comment: I return an empty array from my services, which is populated when the AJAX request comes back. This means I can do things like `vm.objects = Objects.get()`. For times like the OP has above, I also set a `promise` property on the array so I can use it if I need to. This might be why he has chosen to have promise on a property.

Comment: If/when you try to use resolvers you're going to be kicking yourself for coming up with your own convention.  When I have had problems similar to yours I hold onto the promise and hand out the same one to later requesters.

Comment: I use resolvers and it works fine. I have a great system for my app but I have invested a lot of time in it to make it work as well as it does. I am not the OP - not having any problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done looks dangerous, because if for any reason `codeService.get()` takes longer than `playersService.getProfiles({..})` then you'll get an error beacuse `codes` will be undefined when you try to access `codes.MSP[profiles[i].MSPkey].name`.

#### `$q.all(promises)`

`$q.all` ([docs page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)) takes an array or hash of promises and returns its own promise which will only be resolved when all of the others are:

```
$q.all({
  codes: codesService.get().$promise,
  profiles: playersService.getProfiles({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise
})
.then( function (results) {
  var profiles = results.profiles;
  var codes = results.codes;
  for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
    profiles[i].name = codes.MSP[profiles[i].MSPkey].name;
  }
  vm.profiles = profiles;
});
```